# Custom UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom UICollectionViewCell with an oval(with a border) and a label. The cell will change its size based on the size of the label.

**Why does my view get warped?**

[image]

**GOAL**

[image]

**1.** create a prototype cell in Interface builder with a subclass of UIView with grey border. It has top, bottom, trailing, & leading constraint constant of 4.

**2.** I add label (not subview of bordered view explained above) with top, bottom, trailing, & leading constraint constant of 8.

**3.** I add IBOutlet of collectionViewFlowLayout so I can set estimated size (this is for cell resizing).

> collectionViewFLowLayout.estimatedItemSize =
>   UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize

**4.** The rest is boilerplate like conforming to UICollectionViewDataSource

Here is Custom view class.

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }

}
```

Comment: place a label inside a view with top,bottom,leading and trailing constraints and make the cornerRaduis of the view  =  it's height /2

Comment: How you are setting corner radius to label?. show some code

Comment: @mayursinhzala I only set corner radius of view subclass like this:  `self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2`

Comment: @Sh_Khan didn't work. still warped.

Comment: Can u share that subclass of the view

Comment: @Sh_Khan just did

Comment: where is the initalization of it in code i mean it's frame

Comment: try to make it's height static say 50 and it's cornerRadius 25 and see results , i think the problem is in autolayout or frame setting

Comment: @Sh_Khan can't do that. height is dynamic since the frame of the view is constrained to the size of the cell- which changes size dynamically based on intrinsic size of the label. I think thats the problem.

Comment: Drag the view as IBOutlet and in cell awakeFromNib do this        self.tomatoView.cornerRadius = self.tomatoView.frame.height / 2

Comment: still didn't work.

Comment: "Why does my view get warped?"  That's apparently because of self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2

Comment: @ElTomato `self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2` is the computation for a perfect oval. The image I supplied shows how the view is  warped because it is not an oval.

Comment: I think its a problem with autolayout..you need to manage autolaout properly if any. and need the corner radius for view static like 5 or 10. radius with half of height will give you a circle which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your corner radius is little too much, try decreasing it. This,

```
 self.frame.height / 2
```

seems to be a wrong proportion, try increasing the denominator /3,/4 etc.